# HDDs periodically failing

Tags: hard-drive

A couple of months ago I started having issues with 2 HDDs installed in my PC.

At some point (~ once every 2-3 weeks) while I'm using my PC as usual, one of the HDDs suddenly stops responding, disk usage increases to 100%, and in a couple of minutes the HDD disappears from the system altogether. Windows event logs only show generic error messages (eg "Hardware failure") with no details and no error codes.

After that the HDD is not even detected in BIOS, and the only way I can get it working is by detaching the SATA cable and plugging into a different slot on the motherboard.

The strange part is that I recently did an upgrade of my PC replacing all the hardware except those 2 HDDs and the power supply unit, but the problem still exists. I find it somewhat unlikely that the problem is in the HDDs themselves, because they are of different age and from different vendors, and the problems started happening to both of them simultaneously.

Can you suggest any utilities (for Windows) or different ways that can help detect the cause of this problem? Can the problem be in the PSU (as it's the only other thing in the PC that I didn't replace during an upgrade)?

Edit: Here is the SMART status of my HDDs (only one of them shows error):

HDD1:

[image]

HDD2:

[image]

Comment: What is the S.M.A.R.T. status of those drives?

Comment: it might be that only one of the disk is broken and somehow affects the other disk with its fault. I would start by testing if the error occurs even if only one disk is installed.

Comment: @Hennes, I added the SMART status, please see my edit

Comment: please use `i.stack.imgur.com` in the future

Comment: Airflow reading could just be an unsupported value.  HDD2 sector pending otoh is somewhat worrysome. If that increases than that disk is in trouble. (Note that errors are fine. Rapidly increasing errors are not, and a single snapshot of a value does not point either way).

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind the S.M.A.R.T. values of HDD1 I won't worry much about it because this parameter is considered informational and it doesn't directly indicate imminent drive failure. In short, it indicates the temperature of the air inside the HDD housing, but if possible I'd suggest to make a backup of any important data you have stored on it just in case.

As for HDD2, the situation there is different. Current Pending Sectors are active visible bad sectors that cannot be read but are still visible to the operating system. These are dangerous and cause a lot of problems, which is why I would suggest to change this drive either by applying for a RMA if it's still under warranty, or by simply looking for a replacement unit. If you have any important data back it up.

Hope this helps and best of luck!